# Multiple Boxlayouts only using half the space

Tags: java, boxlayout

I'm redesigning a UI that had everything statically laid out which is absolutely horrible to work with. I'm currently redesigning it with each little piece in a boxlayout as shown in the image below.

The issue I am having is that when having nested BoxLayouts I'm getting this issue where the second one (that also has nested boxlayouts) only uses half the width. Note that the UI is not finished otherwise, but this half-width thing is really annoying.

[image: Boxlayout issues]

The UI in the capture location panel is currently statically set (as in it has set bounds and no layout) because I haven't got to it yet.

The main UI for this is a split pane with a BorderLayout on the left consisting of only a button to the south for now (middle will be a JList eventually).

On the right it is a vertical BoxLayout containing a horizontal boxlayout for the top bottoms, a horizontal (with nested vertical for each the ID/Species/Gender).
Added to the bottom of this is the Site Survey Panel which has it's own nested panels as well.

I can post some code if necessary (it's a big ugly mess right now though) but is this a layout manager issue or a code issue? Are you allowed to nest layouts like this? I'm not using a layout builder, this is all by hand... I feel like it makes cleaner code even if it's a bit of a pain to setup.

Answer (score 0):

After spending a couple of hours (and posting this question) of working on this I figured out it has to do with alignment, and you have to set the panels X alignment to CENTER via code:

```
        panelSiteSurvey.setAlignmentX(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
```

Which makes it look like this:
[image: fixed boxlayout]

Hopefully this helps someone in the future who gets this issue.